# ROBLOX - Why isn't my sword script working?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a sword in replicated storage. I clone it and set its parent to the player's Character in workspace. But the sword script doesn't work, it doesn't Activate when I click it. It only works if I put the sword in starter pack. What's going on?

```
Tool.Activated:Connect(function()
    print("Attacking...")
    if Debounce == false then
        Debounce = true
            
        local Humanoid = Tool.Parent.Humanoid
        local animator = Humanoid:WaitForChild("Animator")
        local AnimTrack = animator:LoadAnimation(Slash)
        
        AnimTrack:Play()
        wait(waitTime)
        Debounce = false
        print("Attacked!")
    end
end)
```

The print function doesn't even run.